# Postfix and Amazon SES - forwarding emails - problem with "Delivered-To" header

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, postfix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am running postfix using Amazon SES as the mail transport. Mail is sent out fine, however when I receive mail and try to forward it using a virtual alias, I get this error in the mailog:

```
 (Command died with status 1: "/ses/ses-send-email.pl". Command output: Illegal header 'Delivered-To'. )
```

I see that SES does not support the 'Delivered-To' header so how can I forward email? I have softbounce ON if that means anything, maybe turning it off will work?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a year old but why use the script when Postfix handles relaying through SES just fine using SMTP.

You can either setup your `relayhost` if the only email being sent is from a verified sender or verified domain or you can use `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` to relay only those domains and senders verified.

In either case you would start by setting up the SASL password for SMTP AUTH. I use `/etc/postfix/sasl_password` and it should follow the format of:

```
email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com    SES-USER:SES-USER-PASSWORD
```

Update to use the SMTP host from your AWS SES Console and the appropriate SES SMTP user credentials. Next you need to configure the SMTP SASL client settings in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` by adding the following:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
```

Now run `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_password` and that is all set. Now you have to decide if you're relaying everything or just verified senders/domains. If relaying everything then simply add the following to your `main.cf`:

```
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

On the other hand if you only want to send verified senders/domains then add the following to your `main.cf` instead:

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_maps
```

Then in `/etc/postfix/relayhost_maps` add your verified senders/domains following the format of:

```
verified@example.com    email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
@example.net            email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Run that file through `postmap /etc/postfix/relayhost_maps` and do a `postfix reload` and you should be sending emails through SES.

Comment: They started supporting SMTP for SES only in December 2011.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify `prepend_delivered_header = file` to disable inserting 'Delivered-To' header when forwarding. See [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#prepend_delivered_header) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could [pre-process the forwarded message to rename **all** of the headers that Amazon doesn't like](http://evanhoffman.com./evan/2011/05/16/amazon-ses-illegal-header-errors/).

Answer (score 1):

You can edit ses-send-email.pl to convert illegal headers to X- headers.

Check here for sample code: http://www.evanhoffman.com/evan/2011/08/02/amazon-ses-illegal-headers-with-ses-send-email-pl-followup/

Answer (score 1):

I use header_checks and REPLACE action in postfix like so:

`/^(Delivered-To:.*)$/ REPLACE X-$1`